# Set header in Excel for worksheet 2

Tags: c#, excel, header, worksheet

I habe some problems with setting the header for my worksheet 2

Here is my code:

```
            Excel.Application xlApp1 = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet1 = new Excel.Worksheet();
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet2 = new Excel.Worksheet();
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            xlWorkBook = xlApp1.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlWorkSheet1 = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1); // Sheet1
            xlWorkSheet1.Name = "XX";
            xlWorkSheet2 = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(2); // Sheet2
            xlWorkSheet2.Name = "YY";

            Excel.Range headerRange = xlApp1.get_Range("A1", "V1");
            headerRange.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;

            for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {

                xlApp1.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;

            }
```

Should I make new Excel Application for new header for Worksheet 2? but i doesn't make any sense. Can anyone help me with it? thanks you guys...

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you want to insert the same header into all worksheets? Please provide more information about what you exactly want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I want to have Header 1 in Workshhet 1 and Header 2 in Worksheet 2, it means that I have different headers

Comment: You mean you want to make it dynamic ? Automatically assign the name of the header to the corresponding worksheet?

Comment: yes, that's correct. I have DataGridView2, which has another tableview with differnt header and want to convert it in Excel with same application, workbook but another worksheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write to any cell you want, including the header cells. Just choose the worksheet in which you want to insert the header.

```
Excel.Range headerRange = xlWorkSheet1.get_Range("A1", "V1");
headerRange.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
headerRange.Value = "Header text 1";

headerRange = xlWorkSheet2.get_Range("A1", "V1");
headerRange.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
headerRange.Value = "Header text 2";
```

Comment: thank you very much, now I know where I did mistake, I just changed xlApp1  to xlWorksheet1 and now I cann add as many headers to worksheets as I want. Once more thank you